# ODAC 11.2 Rel. 4 table and field names casing and numbers issues in EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, odp.net

Just migrated ODP.NET 11.2 Release 4 from Devart DotConnect for Oracle http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/ but I got so many issues.

1. Number(1,0) data type must be translated as bool instead of Int16 or
   short. Devart translated it correctly. I solved the issue by adding

   ```
      <add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)"/>
   ```
2. Number(9,2) is translated as Decimal while it should be double. Devart translate it
   double and this is correct. We need double datatype for this. Table
   names are not adjusted if transformed as C# Class. For example I
   have table "PRODUCTS" EF made a class "PRODUCTS" also with the same
   casing. Devart on the other hand created "Products" which is exactly
   the correct naming translation.
3. Field names are not adjusted if transformed as C# Class properties. For example table "PRODUCTS" has field PRODUCT_NAME it should be ProductName if translated into C#
   Class property. Devart does it correctly.

Table Names and Classnames should be in Proper Case if translated to C#.
Underscores for table names should be removed.

Comment: Please report issues you are having to the ODP.NET forum. Specify that you are porting from Devart. That way if they are bugs they can be fixed as quickly as possible. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=146 Christian Shay Oracle

Comment: Thanks! I did but as of now no solutions posted

Comment: @ChristianShay According to the Oracle forum, this is not a bug, but a feature. Any chance that as a PM at Oracle, you can have this "feature" fixed? I think this is a major "feature" and may affect many clients. P.S. As an Oracle client, can I get this prioritized by filing an official service request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **bool mapping** issue, you can find my solution here:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10402873#10402873

For the **double mapping** issue, there seem to be no solutions so far: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10402783#10402783

Regarding the **names transformation** issue, Microsoft's provider for MSSQL doesn't do that automatically either.
You can rename everything manually, however, that is very annoying to do.
(Good to know that Devart can do that automatically.)